# Quitar decimales a un numero en c#

Tags: c#

Tengo un query en c# el cual me arroja resultados numéricos pero necesito guardarlos en una variable pero sin decimales.
aqui mi codigo:

```html
string query="select nombre, cantidad1, cantidad2 from tbl";
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
SqlDataReader reader = cm.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Read())
{
string nombre = reader["nombre"].ToString();
string cantidad1 = reader["cantidad1"].ToString();
string cantidad2 = reader["cantidad2"].ToString();
 }
```

```html
Resultado:
Miguel 496.85417 554.7479225

Resultado esperado
Miguel 496 554
```

Comment: Asigna el resultado a una variable de tipo entero, así te truncará los decimales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta solo modificar esta parte:

```
string cantidad1 = reader["cantidad1"].ToString();
string cantidad2 = reader["cantidad2"].ToString();
```

Por:

```
string cantidad1 = reader["cantidad1"].ToString().Split('.')[0];
string cantidad2 = reader["cantidad2"].ToString().Split('.')[0];
```

En el ejemplo anterior solo eliminarias la parte decimal.

Puedes hacerlo convirtiendolo a un numero decimal y redondeandolo a 0 lugares despues de la coma, o remover la parte decimal sin redondear. Toma el que más se adapte a tus necesidades

```
//Sin redondear solo eliminando la parte de los decimales
string cantidad1 = Math.Floor(Convert.ToDecimal(reader["cantidad1"])).ToString();
string cantidad2 = Math.Floor(Convert.ToDecimal(reader["cantidad2"])).ToString();

//Redondeando a 0 lugares despues de la coma 
string cantidad1 = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(reader["cantidad1"]), 0).ToString();
string cantidad2 = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(reader["cantidad2"]), 0).ToString();
```

Comment: Genial, gracias

Comment: La acabe de editar con mas opciones :)

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

```
string cantidad1 = (int)reader["cantidad1"].ToString();  

string cantidad2 = (int)reader["cantidad2"].ToString();
```

Yo lo que hize fue castear  bueno a mi me funciono de otra forma